# Move Files That Do Not Exist

Tags: c#

I need copy files from my local hard drive to an external hard drive.  My thought is, I only want to copy the files that do not currently exist.  I am sure there is a much easier way to do as such, but this is where my mind went first.

My thoughts on how to accomplish this:
1) Get a list of all files on my C: drive and write to a text file
2) Get a list of all files on my L: drive (backup) and write to a text file
3) Compare C: drive text file to L: drive text file to find the files that do not exist
4) Write results of the files that do not exist to an array
5) Iterate through the newly created array and copy the files to the L: drive

Is there a more effective/time efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Sounds good to me, except you don't really need to write the file list to a file, just store them in memory. Don't forget to traverse your directories.

Comment: [Robocopy?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851678.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "I only want to copy the files that do not currently exist." This sounds like the barber paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox

Comment: A more effecent way? Sure just use [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx). `robocopy.exe C:\ L:\ /e` You also may want `/sec` or `/copyall` if you want the attribute information copied too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain/crashmstr -- as emberassed as I am to say I have nver used robocopy!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For sure you don't want to create text files listing file names, and then compare them. That will be inefficient and clunky. The way to do this is to walk through the source directories looking for all the files. As you go, you'll be creating a matching destination path for each file. Just before you copy the file you need to decide whether or not to copy it. If a file exists at the destination path, skip copying.

Some enhancements on that might include skipping copying only if the file exists and the last modified date/time and file size match. And so on, I'm sure you can imagine variants on this.

One thing that you might not want to do is build a list of all the files first, and then start copying. It may very well be more efficient to copy files as you are iterating over the source directory. For example you could use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) to do this in an efficient way.

Of course, you don't need to write a program to do this. Thousands already exist, some of which are quite effective.